# showing jasper report from spring boot app in angular app

Tags: angular, spring

I want help for showing jasper report from spring boot app in angular app
thinks 
this is my code generating jasper pdf

```
@GetMapping(value = "/print/{id}")
public void report(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws Exception {

    final String invoice_template = "/jasper/invoice_template.jrxml";

    Invoice invoice = invoiceRepo.getOne(id);

    File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("invoice", ".pdf");

    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters.put("invoice", invoice);

    try (FileOutputStream pos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)) {

        final JasperReport report = jrxmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(invoice_template);

        final JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                Collections.singletonList("Invoice"));

        JasperReportsUtils.renderAsPdf(report, parameters, dataSource, pos);

    }

    try (FileOutputStream pos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)) {
        final JasperReport report = jrxmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(invoice_template);

        final JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                Collections.singletonList("Invoice"));

        JasperReportsUtils.renderAsPdf(report, parameters, dataSource, pos);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error(String.format("An error occured during PDF creation: %s", e));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

thinks Hitham S. AlQadheeb i slove my problem with below code

1. **backend**

   ```
   @GetMapping(value = "/print/{id}")
   public @ResponseBody byte[] report(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws Exception {

   final String logo_path = "/jasper/images/stackextend-logo.png";
   final String invoice_template = "/jasper/invoice_template.jrxml";

   Invoice invoice = invoiceRepo.getOne(id);

   File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("invoice", ".pdf");

   log.info(String.format("Invoice pdf path : %s", pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()));

   final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

   parameters.put("logo", getClass().getResourceAsStream(logo_path));
   parameters.put("invoice", invoice);

   try (FileOutputStream pos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)) {
       // Load invoice jrxml template.
       final JasperReport report = jrxmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(invoice_template);

       // Create parameters map.
       // final Map<String, Object> parameters = parameters(invoice);

       // Create an empty datasource.
       final JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
               Collections.singletonList("Invoice"));

       // Render as PDF.
       JasperReportsUtils.renderAsPdf(report, parameters, dataSource, pos);

   } catch (final Exception e) {
       log.error(String.format("An error occured during PDF creation: %s", e));
   }

   byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()));

   return bytes;
   }
   ```
2. **frontend**

**service**

```
 printInvoice(id): any {
const httpOptions = {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
  // 'responseType'  : 'blob' as 'json'        //This also worked
};

return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + '/print/' + id, httpOptions);
 }
```

**ts component**

```
printInvoice(invoice: Invoice) {
  this.invoiceService.printInvoice(invoice.id).subscribe((response) => {

    const file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello evryone now my code work fine on node local server but when  i deploy my app to tomcat server i get below error in console error: 
Blob size: 231
type: "application/json"
__proto__: Blob
headers: n {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8083/stockservice/api/invoices/print/5: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"

Comment: I would avoid `byte[]` (In memory allocation); I'd return `InputStream`

Comment: turn off adblocker if you really want to use blob ;-) this is what i faced

Answer (score 0):

You can respond with the PDF file or something like

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, String>());
String attachment = "attachment; filename=\"filename.pdf\"";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, response.getOutputStream());
```

This should get you started.  You have to be more specific to get better help

This question has an implementation you can use [JasperReport with OutputStream not exporting to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44727792/643500)

Answer (score 0):

```
##SpringBootController## its work cool :)
@GetMapping(value = "/ackPending/pdf/{deptId}")
    public void missoutInward(@PathVariable("deptId") String dept, ModelAndView model, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        logger.info("MISSOUT INWARD PDF REPORT :");
        final InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/missoutInward.jrxml");

        try {
            final JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
            final JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                    inwardService.findPendingAckInward(dept, 1));
            final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("createdBy", "Admin");
            final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, source);
            response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=App_report_en.pdf");

            final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
            /*
             * final String filePath = "\\"; logger.info("File saved At :" + filePath);
             * JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, filePath + "users.pdf");
             */
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
##ANgular 9#####
service.ts##
findPendingInwardsPdf(deptId: string) {
        const httpOptions = {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
            // 'responseType'  : 'blob' as 'json'        //This also worked
        };
        return this.httpClient.get<Inward[]>(URLS.INWARDS + "ackPending/pdf/" + deptId, httpOptions);
    }
------------------
component.ts
search(missout: Missout): void {
        this.inwards = null;
        this.outwards = null;
        if (missout.type == 'Inward') {
            let dept = missout.dept;
            this.inwardService.findPendingInwardsPdf(dept).subscribe((response) => {
                const file = new Blob([response as unknown as BlobPart], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);
            })
        } else {
            this.outwardService.getPendingAck().subscribe(data => {
                this.outwards = data;
            })
        }
    }
```